# Fill Spring @Autowired from static method invokation

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have different static context providers which are called inside the bean. I need to replace this static providers by @autowired annotation. Instead of

```
Context cx = someContextProvider.getProvider();
```

i want something like

```
@Autowired
Context cx;
```

which will be injected by spring through calling someContextProvider.getProvider() method. 
What is the best way to implement this thing? Thx everyone for reply.

PS: I solved that. Solution was simple. To autowire something you just need to specify bean and quialifiers if u have several beans. I didnt know spring good at that time and didnt understand some spring basics. May be this will help somebody

Comment: Are you already injecting `someContextProvider` in your class ?

Comment: Make you PS an answer